# Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol referred from main.o Keil STM32F4

Tags: linker, keil, stm32f4

I am facing a linker error:

```
.\STM32F4xx-Nucleo\DMA_LP_App.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol HAL_UART_Init (referred from main.o).
```

I have added the file `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c` and its path in `option -> C/C++ -> include path` but it's still showing the error.

I have added the file through RTE manager but still the same error.

If I add the file twice it shows:

```
.\STM32F4xx-Nucleo\DMA_LP_App.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol __asm___20_stm32f4xx_hal_uart_c____REV16 multiply defined (by stm32f4xx_hal_uart_1.o and stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o).
```

Kindly let me what is causing this issue and what is possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Issue fixed by using defines to enable modules in project's `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I moved a `.c` file to C++ project. To fix the issue I had to add these lines:

```c
#include "abcxyz.h" //etc
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Contents of your source file */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```